# Proof involving definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm working on Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis. We defined continuity as

> A function $f : M \to N$ is continuous if it preserves sequential
> convergence: f sends convergent sequences in $M$ to convergent sequences in $N$,
> limits being sent to limits. That is, for each sequence $(p_n)$ in $M$ which converges to
> a limit $p$ in $M$, the image sequence $(f(p_n)$) converges to $fp$ in $N$.

Now question 13 is

> Assume that $f : M \to N$ is a function from one metric space to another which
> satisfies the following condition: If a sequence $(p_n)$ in $M$ converges then the
> sequence $(f(p_n))$ in N converges. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

Is this not the same definition of continuity or do I just need to show that the image sequence converges to $fp$?

Comment: Exactly what you said, you need to show $f(p_n)$ not only converges but that the limit is $f(p)$.

Comment: Is the second statement true? For example, in $\mathbb{R}$, take $f(x)=0$ except $f(0)=1$. Then $1/n$ converges (to $0$) and $f(1/n)=0$ converges also. So $f$ satisfies the second property but is not continuous.

Comment: @Chrystomath I don't think your $f$ does satisfy the second property.

Comment: @Chrystomath The definition requires a certain property for **each** sequence that converges to a limit in $M$. You have a function that you have shown satisfies the property for **one** sequence. (Actually, it satisfies the property for many sequences, but not for sequences that converge to $0$ like $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$ or like $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k, 0, a_{k+2}, 0, a_{k+4}, 0, \ldots$.)

Comment: @DavidK So $a_1,a_2,0,0,\ldots$ converges (to $0$) and $f(a_1)=0, f(a_2)=0, 1,1,\ldots$ converges also (to $1$). It still satisfies property (2). I think you mean something like $a_1,0,a_2,0,\ldots$ with $a_n\to0$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Of course a "sequence[] that converge[s] to $0$ [...] like $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k, 0, a_{k+2}, 0, a_{k+4}, 0, \ldots$" must have the property that $a_n\to 0.$ But you're right, only that example is really a counterexample; I was wrong about the sequence that ends in $0,0,0,\ldots.$

Comment: Did you manage to prove it?

Comment: Yes I did. Used a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any convergent sequence $(p_n)$ in $M$, let $p$ be its limit and we construct a new sequence $(x_n)$ where $x_{2a-1}=p_a$ and $x_{2a}=p$ for all $a\in \mathbb N$ (so it looks like $p_1,p,p_2,p,p_3,p,...$). And $(x_n)$ clearly also converges to $p$, thus $(f(x_n))$ also converges. Say its limit is $l$.

We have $l=f(p)$ since $\forall \epsilon>0$ we have $d_N(f(p),l)<\epsilon$ (since $(f(x_n))$ converges to $l$). Thus, in the sequence $(f(x_n))$, if we take $f(p)$ terms out, it becomes the sequence $(f(p_n))$ and it clearly also converges to $f(p)$. Therefore $f$ preserves sequential convergence and thus is continuous.